# Can the content of an XML element be bounded?

Tags: xml, dtd

I am trying to write a DTD, and I want to define an element BOOKTYPE, that can be either ONE, TWO or THREE. Is there a way I can ensure that only one of these values can be entered inside the element?

Note:
1. I know how to do this in an attribute, but not sure how to accomplish with elements.
2. I want a way of doing this INSIDE the DTD, not using a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Not in DTD, sorry. You only get to specify [what elements may appear as children, and whether text content (#PCDATA) can appear or not](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#elemdecls). You don't get a say in what the text content is.

You'd have to move the data to an attribute, or use a schema language more powerful than old-and-clunky DTD.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can ensure that only
>   one of these values can be entered
>   inside the element?

Yes, with an XML Schema Definition (XSD) containing an [XML Enumeration](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/02/05/wxs-enum.html).  Here is an example one for currencies:

```
<xsd:simpleType name = "iso3currency">
 <xsd:restriction base = "xsd:string">
  <xsd:enumeration value = "AUD"/><!-- Australian Dollar -->
  <xsd:enumeration value = "BRL"/><!-- Brazilian Real -->
  <xsd:enumeration value = "CAD"/><!-- Canadian Dollar -->
  <xsd:enumeration value = "CNY"/><!-- Chinese Yen -->
  <xsd:enumeration value = "EUR"/><!-- Euro -->
  <xsd:enumeration value = "GBP"/><!-- British Pound -->
  <xsd:enumeration value = "INR"/><!-- Indian Rupee -->
  <xsd:enumeration value = "JPY"/><!-- Japanese Yen -->
  <xsd:enumeration value = "RUR"/><!-- Russian Rouble -->
  <xsd:enumeration value = "USD"/><!-- US Dollar -->
  <xsd:length value = "3"/>
 </xsd:restriction>
```

This restricts the value of the element to one of the listed enumeration values and a length of 3.

To use it, you have to pass your XML and XSD through a [validator](http://www.xmlme.com/Validator.aspx).  An example of how to do this in .NET is here:

**HOW TO: Validate XML Fragments Against an XML Schema in Visual C#.NET**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318504

Comment: Indeed. But is it possible in DTD's as well? I believe they're more limited than XSD's in some ways.